# Displaying accented characters using VBA in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, utf-8, powerpoint, utf

I have created a PowerPoint to display 5 random words from a .txt file following [this excellent tutorial](http://www.thetechtrain.co.uk/2016/04/28/generate-random-words-in-powerpoint-from-text-file/).

The problem is, the words in my .txt file are Spanish, so have accents on them. When PowerPoint displays them, they look corrupt. For example Perú looks like PerÃ°.

This is my code:

```
Public myArray, Word1, Word2, Word3, Word4, Word5

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)

If SSW.Presentation.SlideShowSettings.StartingSlide Then
Randomize
Label1.Caption = ""
Label2.Caption = ""
Label3.Caption = ""
Label4.Caption = ""
Label5.Caption = ""

Dim path
path = ActivePresentation.path & "\palabras.txt"

Open path For Input As #1
filecontent = Input(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1

myArray = Split(filecontent, vbCrLf)

End If

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Word1 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
Word2 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
Word3 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
Word4 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
Word5 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)

Do While Word1 = Word2
Word2 = Int((UBound(myArray)) * Rnd)
Loop

Label1.Caption = myArray(Word1)
Label2.Caption = myArray(Word2)
Label3.Caption = myArray(Word3)
Label4.Caption = myArray(Word4)
Label5.Caption = myArray(Word5)


End Sub
```

I know the end of it is messy too, I didn't know how to get it so that Word3, 4 and 5 didn't repeat. It's my first time using VBA.

Can anyone help?

[Files](https://ufile.io/rdohc9gq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA and COM use Unicode internally. But when interacting with the Windows API VBA uses ANSI as Windows 9x didn't have Unicode API calls.

The `Open` statement is depreciated. It will be calling Windows' `CreateFileA`. Using the `FileSystemObject`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/openastextstream-method

Make sure you specify Unicode when opening the file.

OR set your non Unicode settings to Spanish or something.

```
   Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
   Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
   Dim fso, f, ts
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   fso.CreateTextFile "test1.txt"   ' Create a file.
   Set f = fso.GetFile("test1.txt")
   Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateUseDefault)
   ts.Write "Hello World"
   ts.Close
   Set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)
   TextStreamTest = ts.ReadLine
   ts.Close
```

From Help.

---

```
Set TS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile("test1.txt").OpenAsTextStream(1, -1)
x = ts.readall
```

Comment: How do I change it? Sorry this is my first time doing this.

Comment: In Regional Settings.

Comment: The regional settings of PowerPoint? So I don't need to do anything to the VB code? I really appreciate your help and I'm sorry for not understanding.

Comment: In Windows Settings.

Comment: Thank you. I have set non-unicode to Spanish, restarted, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: How do I "specify Unicode when opening the file"?

Comment: If a file is Unicode you have to read it into a byte array. If it has a BOM you have to strip it. Then use `StrConv` to convert to a string.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't know how to do that. I guess this is going to be too difficult to explain.